# gperftools - measure only one function

Tags: c++, profiler

I have a C++ application with threads (via boost).

I want to profile only one thread with [gperftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools), because I've read it has minimal performance overhead and can work in multi-threaded applications.

Now the situation is very simple, only one thread needs to be analysed.

So I've put `ProfilerStart` into the thread's main function:

```
void run() {
  ProfilerStart("thread.log");

  initFunc1();

  while(mRunning) {
    loopFunc1();
    loopFunc2();
    loopFunc3();
  }

  endFunc1();

  ProfilerStop();
}
```

Recompiled the code and linked it against `profile` library.

I ran the program, it created `thread.log`, then I've converted this into callgrind format (`pprof --callgrind ./app thread.log > profile.callgrind`).

Then I opened the callgrind log with [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html), and it contains calls from everywhere (i.e. not just the functions between ProfilerStart and ProfilerStop).

This would not bother me, but still it's very interesting why it contains anything that is outside?

But the real problem is that I can not see any of my functions in the callgraph what is originally between ProfilerStart and ProfilerStop.

Main goal: check inner functions about their timings (especially in the loop).

With pure logging I could "measure" that one loop usually takes more than 10ms which is huge (between two `loopFunc1` calls).